# Can't open a new project, Visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to create a new project, but dosen't get a soulution explore, instad i get a team explorer. What i am doing is: File -> New -> Project -> Visual c# -> Web -> ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) -> Empty -> Ok

I want a emptry project, so i can code html/css and javascript, but i don't get the soulution explore... Looks like this when it's created: [image]

Hope som1 can help me, so i can begin code html/css again, i have tried to reset layout in window. Thanks

Comment: Go to View/Solution Explorer instead of the team explorer tab

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried opening solution explorer manually? 
It can be done by View > Solution Explorer  or either by clicking Ctrl+Alt+L

Hope it helps

Comment: That helped! Thannks alot

Comment: I'm happy that it helped. Can you accept my answer as the answer to your question?